# Package subcaption Error: This package can't be used in cooperation

Tags: subcaption, books

I am writing my thesis with the latex template with overleaf.

The main tex file;

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,openany]{book}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%      THESIS PARAMETERS       %%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Language Option: "tr" or "eng"                (default: "eng")
% Degree Option: "ms" or "phd"                  (default: "ms")
% For Thesis Monitoring Committee Report: "tmc"
% Bibliography Option: "ieee" or "authoryear"   (default: "ieee")

% Example:   \usepackage[tr, phd, tmc]{ytuthesis}
%            \usepackage[eng, ms]{ytuthesis}
%            \usepackage[tr, ms, authoryear]{ytuthesis}

\usepackage[tr, phd]{ytuthesis}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
```

In a separate chapter tex file I want to use subtable;

```
\chapter{intro}
....
....
\begin{table}
    \begin{subtable}{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{tabular}{c|cccc}
            \toprule    
            & User-1 & User-2 & ... &User-100 \\ 
            \midrule
            Project-1& 0 & 51   & ... & 96 \\
            Project-2& 7 &  0  & ... & 0 \\
            Project-3& 0 & 0   & ... & 4 \\
            ...& ... & ...   & ...  & ... \\
            Project-n& 0 & 34  & ... & 0 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Actual values of the metric}
        \label{tab:pivottableA}
    \end{subtable}
    \hfill
    \begin{subtable}{.5\textwidth}
        \begin{tabular}{c|cccc}
            \toprule    
            & User-1 & User-2 &... &User-100 \\ 
            \midrule
            Project-1& 0 & 4   & ... & 10 \\
            Project-2& 0.08 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
            Project-3& 0 & 0   &... & 0.5 \\
            ...& ... & ...   & ... & ... \\
            Project-n& 0 & 3  &... & 0 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Normalized values of the metric}
        \label{tab:pivottableN}
    \end{subtable}
    \caption{A sample project-developer matrix belongs to the metric \textit{issue\_opened}}
    \label{tab:pivottable}
\end{table}
```

It doesn't work. It gives an error about compability;

> Package subcaption Error: This package can't be used in cooperation
>
> (subcaption)                with the subfig package.

In tex file in the related lines, it gives an error;

> Latex error: Environment subtable undefined

How can I solve it?
Is it related the document class?

All source file is in this [link](http://www.fbe.yildiz.edu.tr/media/files/YTU%20Thesis%20Latex-21_07_2020.zip)

The log message is here;

> Package subcaption Error: This package can't be used in cooperation
>
> (subcaption)                with the subfig package.
>
> See the subcaption package documentation for explanation. Type  H
>   for immediate help.  ...
>
> \subcaption@CheckCompatibility
> If you do not understand this error, please take a closer look at the > > documentation of the
> `subcaption' package, especially the section about errors. Try typing
>   to proceed. If that doesn't work, type  X   to quit.

Comment: So you must be including `subfig` somewhere as well, right? Possibly via `ytuthesis`. By the way, where can we source that style file? Can you include your full preamble? Can you include the `.log`?